# Java collection Equality and Contains option

Tags: java

i have a collection i created of type Service

```
   Collection<Service> collection = serviceMap.values();
```

My data that is returned by the collection is of type param.

```
    Service first = collection.iterator().next();
    Set<Param> firstInputParam = first.getInputParamSet();
    Set<Param> firstOutputParam = first.getOutputParamSet();
```

An example of the outputs of firstInputParam and firstOutputParam:

```
    first.getInputParamSet: [J]
    first.getOutputParamSet: [C]
```

My goal and my issue is that i need to find a way to compare if the following outputParam is in the  set of second.getInputParamSet.

For example i.getInputParamSet contains:

```
     Input ParamSet: [E, C]
```

ive tried the following

```
      if (i.getInputParamSet().equals(first.getOutputParamSet())){
```

&

```
      if (i.getInputParamSet().contains(first.getOutputParamSet())){
```

but neither of these two methods have worked can anyone assist me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have [overridden `hashCode` and `equals` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) in your `Param` class and use [`containsAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
if (i.getInputParamSet().containsAll(first.getOutputParamSet()))
```